# Issue selecting and storing hour and min into a variable from cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, cursor

I have a trouble with this nested cursors. I should get hour and min from the timestamp inside the two cursors then sum and store them into a variable, so that I can use it after in the same code. I use the extract function as it follows:

```
DECLARE
    
    CURSOR cur1 IS
        (SELECT *
        FROM ((Patient P JOIN Presence Pr ON P.idP=Pr.id_PRP)
               JOIN Loc L ON L.idL=Pr.id_PRL) LEFT JOIN Contact C ON
               P.idP=C.id_PR1);
             
    
    CURSOR cur2 IS
            ((SELECT *
             FROM (((Patient P JOIN Visit V ON P.idP=V.id_PV)
                    JOIN Presence Pr ON P.idP=Pr.id_PRP))
             WHERE :NEW.id_VSW = V.idV));
             
    np cur2%ROWTYPE;
    
    st_c1 number;
    et_c1 number;
    st_np number;
    et_np number;
    
BEGIN
    FOR curV IN cur1 
    LOOP
    
        OPEN cur2;
        
        FETCH cur2 INTO np;
       
        SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM curV.time_Start)+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM curV.time_Start)) INTO st_c1 FROM DUAL;
        SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM curV.time_End)+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM curV.time_End)) INTO et_c1 FROM DUAL;
        SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM np.time_Start)+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM np.time_Start)) INTO st_np FROM DUAL;
        SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM np.time_End)+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM np.time_End)) INTO et_np FROM DUAL;
        
        IF (((st_cl <= et_np AND st_cl >= st_np) OR (st_np <= et_cl AND st_np >= st_c1))
            ...
        END IF;
        CLOSE cur2;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The time_Start and time_End attributes are like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-02-22 13:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

it gives me this error:

```
36/3      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
36/40     PLS-00201: identifier 'ST_CL' must be declared
```

What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you like brackets? Most of yours can be skipped. Your logic will not work, better use like `st_c1 := 60*EXTRACT(HOUR FROM curV.time_Start) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM curV.time_Start);`

Comment: Please describe the problem you trying to resolve not the code you are trying to use.  Why are you adding hours and minuets, the results do not make any since. After all  05:50  AM (55) would  be greater the 10:40 AM (50) and but lesr than 10:50 AM  (60). What happens when the start to end time crosses midnight i.e start 23:00 PM end 01:00 AM the next day.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `ST_CL`, but `ST_C1` (number one) - at least, that's how you declared it.